# PHP Cannot redeclare function error: Why am I getting this error?

Tags: php, soap, include, fatal-error

I have two PHP scripts that include the same include file. Also, for testing purposes, I declared the same function that performs SOAP operations in both scripts. In other words, my scripts look like this:

```
#script1.php
include('include.php');

someFn();
function someFn() {
  //SOAP code here
}

#script2.php
include('include.php');

someFn();
function someFn() {
  //SOAP code here
}
```

Whenever I try to run one script and then the other, I get the following error:
PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare someFn() (previously declared in script1.php) in script2.php

I cannot understand why I'm getting this error. I've coded similar situations before, but never gotten this error, so I suspect that the executing of the SOAP code (specifically, the `new SoapClient` constructor and `$client->__setSoapHeaders` method) is causing this error.

What's also interesting is if I comment out the include file (which, by the way, does *not* have `someFn` defined in it) and then rerun the script, I don't get any errors and everything is fine.

What is happening here?
Thank you.

**Edit**: After playing around some more, I found out that if I have the following situation:

```
#script1.php
include('include.php'); //someFn defined in include.php

someFn();

#script2.php
someFn();
function someFn() {
  //SOAP code here
}
```

And then run `script2.php` and then `script1.php` after that, I get the same error. It's almost as if after I run `script2.php` and close it, the process continues in PHP so that when I run `script1.php`, I get the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

**Edit #2**: This is honestly the most confusing thing ever. I started over by creating two brand new files in the same directory as the other files and then all I added to both files was the following code:

```
<?php

  include('include.php');
```

And when I run either file, I get all the SOAP output that was generated from the other files in the directory. I haven't bothered trying to restart the server, but at this point, I can only assume that something really weird is cached on the server.

Anyway, I resolved the issue by simply creating a new directory and then moving the file I wanted to that directory and re-executing it. By doing that, I got no errors and everything is fine.

Thanks everyone for your assistance.

Comment: That is all quite unusual. What are the contents of `include.php`?

Comment: The contents of `include.php` are plentiful. It's basically a file that has a bunch of helper functions I often use.

Comment: The contents of the two functions are identical. Obviously, I wouldn't normally want to do that, but I was doing it for testing purposes, as it shouldn't actually matter and create an error.

Comment: Also, I tried commenting out the SOAP code and even changing the function name (but to the same new name in both scripts), and I still get the error. I will investigate the issue more this evening. So confused...

Comment: Also, `include_once` caused the same error.

Comment: How are you running the scripts one after the other?

Comment: Your code is just a sample, we would need to see the real code (both script#1 and script#2) to find the error that you are not seeing.

Comment: I will look into the problem more this evening and try to better revise my question for tomorrow. Thank you.